# row-wise iteration in a dataframe where each row depends on previous row calculation in R

Tags: r

In a dataframe I'd like to use previous row calculated result in order to get current row calculated result involving other current row values. Also I need to apply some conditions and it has to be done by a dimension product_id. The key point is that the target column is at the same time used to calculate itself. I reproduced a sample in Excel and it looks like this:

[image: click here to see sample data]

```
product_id <- c(rep(1,each=9), rep(2,each=8))
dates <- c("24/09/20","25/09/20","26/09/20","27/09/20","28/09/20","29/09/20", "30/09/20","01/10/20","02/10/20","08/10/20","09/10/20","10/10/20","11/10/20","12/10/20","13/10/20","14/10/20","15/10/20")
date <- as.Date(dates, "%d/%m/%y")
num_day <- c(1:9, 1:8)
production <- c(rep(4,each=9), rep(3.5,each=8))
demand <- c(0,0,3,1,3,20,0,1,3,0,1,2,5,0,15,1,3)


df <- data.frame (product_id,date,num_day,production,demand)
```

Target column to be created is stock. The df is sorted by product_id and then by date, so, the order of the rows is meaningful.

Conditions: both can be applied with one statement but I split them to make it clear

Condition 1: if (stock previous day + production current day - demand
current day <= 0, 0, stock previous day + production current day -
demand current day)

Condition 2: if num_day = 1, stock = production current day - demand
current day and it cannot be negative neither if production current
day - demand current day < 0

In Excel it's a pretty straight forward formula but when dealing with large amount of data, more than 1 million rows, it's not possible to do it there. I'm trying to built a function in R but maybe it's not the best approach. Is any way to do it in R?

I tried to use an auxiliary column with accumulative sum, shift columns but it does not work. I think that it's more complex than that

Comment: Please can you use ``dput(data)`` and post the output in your main question rather than posting an image of your data - it makes it much easier for others to reproduce your code. Please also give an example of the desired output.

Comment: excuse me @user438383, it has been the first time I have posted here, I'll write sample's code and desired output for next times

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done using `purrr`'s `accumulate`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(product_id) %>%
  mutate(stock = accumulate(production - demand, ~max(.x + .y, 0))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 17 x 6
# Groups:   product_id [2]
   product_id date       num_day production demand stock
        <dbl> <date>       <int>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1          1 2020-09-24       1        4        0   4  
 2          1 2020-09-25       2        4        0   8  
 3          1 2020-09-26       3        4        3   9  
 4          1 2020-09-27       4        4        1  12  
 5          1 2020-09-28       5        4        3  13  
 6          1 2020-09-29       6        4       20   0  
 7          1 2020-09-30       7        4        0   4  
 8          1 2020-10-01       8        4        1   7  
 9          1 2020-10-02       9        4        3   8  
10          2 2020-10-08       1        3.5      0   3.5
11          2 2020-10-09       2        3.5      1   6  
12          2 2020-10-10       3        3.5      2   7.5
13          2 2020-10-11       4        3.5      5   6  
14          2 2020-10-12       5        3.5      0   9.5
15          2 2020-10-13       6        3.5     15   0  
16          2 2020-10-14       7        3.5      1   2.5
17          2 2020-10-15       8        3.5      3   3
```

The result matches yours and @rjen's, so I am relatively sure this is correct.

Explanation: with `accumulate`, a simple cumulative sum could be implemented as `accumulate(production - demand, ~.x + .y)` (or even shorter as `` accumulate(production - demand, `+`) ``). Using the `max` function here ensures the result never gets lower than 0, which is what you intended.

Comment: many thanks @shizundeiku, nice explanation and really optimized code!!

Answer (score 0):

Until you find a more elegant solution, you can do the following.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(product_id) %>%
  mutate(group = if_else(cumsum(production-demand) < 0 | 
                         num_day == min(num_day), 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(group = if_else(group != 0, row_number(), as.integer(0)),
         group = cumsum(group)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(modDiff = if_else(num_day == min(num_day), 0, production-demand)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(product_id) %>%
  mutate(modDiff = if_else(num_day == min(num_day), production-demand, modDiff),
         modDiff = if_else(num_day == min(num_day) & modDiff < 0, 0, modDiff)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(stock = cumsum(modDiff)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-modDiff, -group)

# # A tibble: 17 x 6
# product_id          date num_day production demand stock
# <dbl>             <date>   <int>      <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1           1 2020-09-24       1        4        0   4  
# 2           1 2020-09-25       2        4        0   8  
# 3           1 2020-09-26       3        4        3   9  
# 4           1 2020-09-27       4        4        1  12  
# 5           1 2020-09-28       5        4        3  13  
# 6           1 2020-09-29       6        4       20   0  
# 7           1 2020-09-30       7        4        0   4  
# 8           1 2020-10-01       8        4        1   7  
# 9           1 2020-10-02       9        4        3   8  
# 10          2 2020-10-08       1        3.5      0   3.5
# 11          2 2020-10-09       2        3.5      1   6  
# 12          2 2020-10-10       3        3.5      2   7.5
# 13          2 2020-10-11       4        3.5      5   6  
# 14          2 2020-10-12       5        3.5      0   9.5
# 15          2 2020-10-13       6        3.5     15   0  
# 16          2 2020-10-14       7        3.5      1   2.5
# 17          2 2020-10-15       8        3.5      3   3
```

Comment: The solution now accommodates all cases.